# How to convert nested Entity to DTO using MapStruct or Java Stream?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, java-stream, hibernate-mapping

In my Spring Boot apps, I generally use projection in order to return joined table results. However, I am trying to use Java Stream to map and return nested entities to the corresponding DTOs. Here is an example that I generally encountered:

**Note:** I setup entity relationship using Hibernate and that part is completely ok. For this reason, I omitted the related code for brevity. Just concentrate on mapping entities to the nested DTOs.

Country has many States, States has many Towns...

***Country:***

```
public class Country {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany(...)
    private Set<State> states = new HashSet<>();
}
```

***State:***

```
public class State {

    private Long id;

    private Long population;

    @ManyToOne(...)
    private Country country;

    @OneToMany(...)
    private Set<Town> towns = new HashSet<>();
}
```

***Town:***

```
public class Town {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToOne()
    private State state;
}
```

I want to get Country list with Country Name, Sum of state population belonging to this country and Town list belonging to the country.

For this purpose, I created the following DTOs, but not sure if it is ok and how can I map the necessary data to this DTO in one step (I don't want to go to database 3 times, instead, I just want to map the country list to the corresponding fields (the list has all of these data as I built the relations properly using Hibernate).

```
@Data
public class CountryResponse {

    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private Set<StateResponse> states;

    private Long population;

    private Set<TownResponse> towns;

    public CountryResponse(Country country) {
        this.id = country.getId();
        this.name = country.getName();

        // ???
        this.states = country.getStates.stream().map(StateResponse::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
        this.towns = this.states.stream().map(TownResponse::new)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

How can I do this? I would also consider using MapStruct if it is better for this scenario?

Comment: Has anybody else have never mapped nested entities using MapStruct or Java Stream?

Comment: MapStruct works with nested objects out of the box using reflexion. If you need to customize it, it is also possible just via the `@Mapping` annotation without writing a code, if your customization is not "too wild". I am confused - is your question *really* related to hibernate, or is it just a general question about mapping between too classes with identical (or similar) fields?

Comment: Actually it is related to mapping nested entity to DTO, but finally I solved the problem using Java Stream and FlatMap properly (I also tried it many times before, but that time I could not)

Comment: Maybe your code was not necessary, I think it was achievable by MapStruct, too, without coding. I always prefer this approach if it is possible.

Comment: Thanks a lot, actually I am looking for MapStruct and will use it in my projects. After that, I would also use it in this mapping operations I think.

Answer (score 1):

To get the sum of state populations, you can use the following stream code

```
country.getStates().stream().map(State::getPopulation).sum();
```

and the list of towns can be fetched as follows

```
country.getStates().stream().map(State::getTowns).flatMap(Set::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. But I am looking for a solution that returns Country list with the population sum of the States inside each country and Towns **by using a single stream** instead of fetching data multiple times. Is that possible?

Comment: By the way, voted up for your helps.